# silverlight: refresh to a specific url

Tags: silverlight

suppose user navigated to silverlight page at root/myurl. When user presses f5 I would like the browser to fetch the content of root/, not root/myurl. Is this possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is write a flag to your local storage that says, in effect, "'root/myurl' is the last URL I visited." And when when someone reloads "root/myurl", check to see if that flag exists. If it does, renavigate to "root/". It's a little complex, but something of that sort ought to work.

The other approach I usually take in these instances, where I find myself wanting behavior that doesn't match how the browser normally behaves, is to figure out why I'm doing things different from everyone else. Quite often (almost always), there's a better and more natural way to do it, if I'll just take a step back and figure out what I'm really wanting.

Comment: well, actually I solved the problem by specifying `JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"` in a top navigation frame. This way url of the app is always root.